# Chromium (Chromodo) rendering issue with Pure-Drawer

Tags: html, css

I am viewing the same page ([Codepen.io/OleVik/full/pjMPqJ/](http://codepen.io/OleVik/full/pjMPqJ/)) in Firefox 40.0.3, Chrome 46.0.2490.86, and Chromodo 45.6.11.383, and have largely the expected result: On the former two, the header has a parallax-effect when scrolling, and toggling the [Pure-Drawer](http://mac81.github.io/pure-drawer/) menus do not cause a snap-to-top in the browser.

However, in Chromodo the parallax-effect does not work. I resolve this by disabling the `height: 100%;`-property on `.pure-pusher-container`, but then this causes a snap-to-top effect when toggling the menus (scrolls to top).

Is this a specific or known issue with how Chromium/Chromodo renders CSS, and what could be the cause? Also, what would be a conceivable remedy for both the parallax-effect and the vertically-independent menu-toggling?

The code used in the Codepen is too long to reproduce here (even though it is simplified for the example), but it can be [edited through this link](http://codepen.io/OleVik/pen/pjMPqJ), raw [HTML looks like](http://codepen.io/OleVik/pen/pjMPqJ.html), and raw [CSS like this](http://codepen.io/OleVik/pen/pjMPqJ.css).

Comment: What exactly is supposed to show? I can't see any difference between SeaMonkey 2.39 and Chromium 46.0.2490.71.

Comment: Sorry, I perhaps should have been clearer: When scrolling, the header image (with the beach) should have a parallax effect, thus moving independently from scrolling. Further, toggling either of the side-menus should maintain the current location in the page, without scrolling back to top. The difference is clear when disabling the `height`-property on `.pure-pusher-container`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more googling, it appears it is a reported Chromium issue with various fixes depending on context. For my code, the necessary ingredient was adding `transform: translate(0,0);` to the wrapping `.blog-header` element. I found this solution in a [Codepen article](http://codepen.io/Rycode/post/chrome-bug-with-fixed-background-and-translate3d).